# indented block in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the msg: 
there is an error in your program: expected an indented block
in here line 4, print data.

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
        print data
        saveFile = open('UkmDB','a')
        saveFile.write(data)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
    except BaseException, e:
        print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: you need to indent after `try:` and the `expect` must be at the same level

Comment: Your indentation is certainly wrong in this post. Are you mixing tabs and spaces, and have tabs configured to expand to every 4th column perhaps? Don't do that, only use spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `try:` you need to indent:

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print data
            saveFile = open('UkmDB','a')
            saveFile.write(data)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
            time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class listener(StreamListener):
  def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        print data
        saveFile = open('UkmDB','a')
        saveFile.write(data)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
    except BaseException, e:
        print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
        time.sleep(5)
```